# what is the default time out value of java.net.Socket in android?

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-networking, socket-timeout-exception

I'm developing a mobile application for android. There, I creating socket and transfer data between android mobiles and windows application (which is run on pc,laptop). I'm using **android 2.3**

Testing mobile **samsung galaxy pop**

The pc and mobiles are connected via USB tithering.

The data transfer correctly.

But one problem is in the middle of application the tithering cancelled by unplug the mobile usb caple from system,then i throws exception.

But some times it does not through any exception it simply waits,Socket also not closed waits for data for reading

So please send the default socket time out time in android

My sample codes are given below

```
    Socket socket=null;
    DataOutputStream dos=null;
    OutputStream os=null;
    InputStream is=null;
    DataInputStream dis=null;

    try
    {
        Log.i(tagName, "b4 creating socket");
        socket=new Socket(this.getIpAddress(),this.getPort_number());                   
        is=socket.getInputStream();             
        dos=new DataOutputStream(os);       
        dis=new DataInputStream(is);            
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException unknown_ex)
    {
        Log.i(tagName, "Exception host unknown : "+unknown_ex.toString());
        unknown_ex.printStackTrace();           
    }
    catch(IOException ioe_ex)
    {
        Log.i(tagName, "ioe Exception : "+ioe_ex.toString());           
        ioe_ex.printStackTrace();           
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.i(tagName, "Exception : "+ex.toString());       
        ex.printStackTrace();       
    }

    if(dos!=null)
    {
        try
        {
            dos.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    if(dis!=null)
    {
        try
        {
            dis.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
    }
    if(socket!=null)
    {
        try
        {
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    socket=null;dos=null;dis=null;      
    Log.i(tagName, "MySocketConnection.connectMe() - end");
```

When I use the code

```
Socket.getSoTimeout()
```

Then it returns 0.

Please all are give your ideas.

Comment: What's the value you get when you call `Socket.getSoTimeout()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default socket read timeout is infinity, as it says in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout(int)), "A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.". If you want a finite value, call `Socket.setSoTimeout().`

Comment: Can you please point out where this is written in the Javadoc?

Comment: "A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout."  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout(int)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the default timeout use `this.socket.setSoTimeout(5000);` but you can try setting a higher timeout value. Here 5000 miliseconds means 5 seconds. Hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: If you don't know the default value, how can you possibly know that setting it to 5000 will increase it?

Comment: it will not increase it i guess..it will set it to 5 seconds

Comment: So how about posting that in your answer in a coherent fashion?